# how can i sort an unordered list of buttons alphabetically without changing appearance?

Tags: javascript, html

so I have an unordered list of buttons. its a relatively long list, and are sorted via some of these:
`display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap; justify-content:space-between;`
is there any way to make all of these buttons sort themselves alphabetically via javascript and keep its original look (not making it look like a list)?

Comment: Why would sorting them change the way they look?

Comment: @Barmar because sorting buttons only works when buttons are placed inside of a <li>, making them ordered.

Comment: You can put the buttons inside a `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the buttons in a div. Create an array of the buttons, sort the array, then put them back into the div in the sorted order.

```
let div = document.getElementById('id-of-div');
let buttons = Array.from(div.children);
buttons.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
div.innerHTML = '';
buttons.forEach(b => div.appendChild(b));
```